# JMeter - Test not running on second call at run time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have set my tests up in the following layout:

```
Test Plam
Test Fragment 
    EP-1(include controller)
    EP-2(include controller)
    EP-3(include controller)
Thread Group
    Parameterized controller
        Module Controller
            EP1
    Parameterized controller
        Module Controller
            EP2
    Parameterized controller
        Module Controller
            EP1     
    Parameterized controller
        Module Controller
            EP3             
    View Results Tree
```

Results:
EP1
EP2
EP3

When running these tests i only get EP1 running once and doesn't run a second time (doesn't even look like it attempts to run)

No information in JMeter log apart from loaded (include controller)

I added the HTTP request directly and have the same issue so did the following set up:

```
    Test Plan
Test Fragment 
    EP-1(include controller)
    EP-2(include controller)
    EP-3(include controller)
Thread Group
    Parameterized controller
            EP1
    Parameterized controller
            EP2
    Parameterized controller
            EP1     
    Parameterized controller
            EP3             
    View Results Tree
```

Still got the same result. Any ideas?

New:
[image: layout]

OUTPUT of this is:

- JWT Token
- Include Controller1 (PUT)
- Include Controller2 (GET)
- HTTP Request (PUT)
- Include Controller1 (PUT)
- HTTP Request (GET)
- Include Controller1 (PUT)

Expected:

- JWT Token
- Include Controller1 (PUT)
- Include Controller2 (GET)
- HTTP Request (PUT)
- Include Controller1 (PUT)
- Include Controller2 (GET)
- HTTP Request (GET)
- Include Controller1 (PUT)
- HTTP Request (GET)
- Include Controller2 (GET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Cache Manager was caching the (GET) request (checkbox)

unchecked that and it worked.

Hopefully this helps anyone having a moment when writing these tests and unable to work out why the following (GET) requests are not being excuted.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest stable [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) and your test plan structure with simple single [Dummy Samplers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) under the Test Fragment in the each included file.

I configured the included Samplers to display current Thread Group iteration using [__threadGroupName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) and [__V() functions combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) like:

```
${__V(__jm__${__threadGroupName}__idx,)}
```

and as you can see everything is executing just fine:

[image]

Comment: Added some more details. I am only writing them at the moment so 1 thread ramp up 1 and 1 loop.